# Correct regression model for independent variable limited 0-100

Tags: r, logistic, least-squares, heteroscedasticity

So I'm having some questions about a regression model I'm trying to fit
The dependent variable is a continuous interval scaled index reaching from 0 to 100. It's severely left-skewed and most observations range somewhere between 70 and 90. In total I have ~75 observations and I'm trying to fit eight independent variables.

Is a linear OLS regression model appropriate here? I looked at the fitted value and it over predicts only once and very limited, by only 3 points. Underprediction is not present

Some have recommended using logistic regression. Is this possible when the dependent variable is not 0 or 1, but after transformation something like 0.85? Also the linear model is heteroscedastic to some extent. now I've read, that heteroscedasticity leads to biased and inconsistent estimates in logistic regression? How could this be treated?
I'm somewhat confused as to the absurd number of possibilities with every recommendation saying something else.

Here you can find the data and the code I used in terms of linear regression with robust standard errors in R

```
structure(list(ID = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", 
                            "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Belarus", "Benin", "Bolivia", 
                            "Burkina Faso", "Burma/Myanmar", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", 
                            "Central African Republic", "Chad", "China", "Cuba", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", 
                            "Djibouti", "Egypt", "Eritrea", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", 
                            "Gabon", "Guinea", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iran", "Iraq", 
                            "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", 
                            "Lebanon", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Mauritania", 
                            "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Oman", 
                            "Pakistan", "Papua New Guinea", "Philippines", "Qatar", "Republic of the Congo", 
                            "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", "Singapore", "Somalia", 
                            "South Sudan", "Sudan", "Syria", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", 
                            "Togo", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
                            "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), 
                     Dep_Var = c(84.26, 89.81, 92.13, 90.74, 96.3, 78.7, 93.52, 
                                 19.44, 70.83, 96.3, 89.81, 86.11, 33.33, 68.52, 71.3, 75.93, 
                                 88.89, 81.94, 100, 80.56, 100, 84.26, 93.52, 89.81, 80.56, 
                                 88.89, 81.48, 78.7, 87.04, 100, 76.85, 64.35, 96.3, 100, 
                                 89.35, 93.52, 100, 92.13, 96.3, 85.19, 95.37, 57.41, 75, 
                                 72.22, 77.78, 93.52, 80.56, 16.67, 61.11, 85.65, 100, 96.3, 
                                 83.8, 100, 86.11, 97.22, 87.04, 90.74, 94.44, 100, 85.19, 
                                 60.19, 86.11, 91.67, 86.11, 73.15, 50, 82.41, 73.15, 77.78, 
                                 58.33, 93.52, 92.59, 89.81, 96.3, 87.04, 96.3, 70.83, 87.96
                     ), Var1 = c(4.127, 5.251, 5.296, 6.541, 6.672, 6.414, 6.78, 
                                 6.062, 7.056, 5.78, 5.786, 4.552, 3.537, 5.527, 5.608, 6.275, 
                                 3.147, 5.291, 6.55, 4.069, 4.996, 4.586, 4.605, 6.525, 5.409, 
                                 6.302, 6.324, 5.558, 3.996, 6.325, 5.951, 4.481, 3.772, 4.786, 
                                 6.746, 5.645, 6.613, 6.603, 6.306, 3.814, 5.482, 6.14, 6.521, 
                                 4.924, 5.121, 5.355, 5.101, 7.214, 6.554, 6.047, 5.636, 7.175, 
                                 4.735, 5.151, 6.116, 4.799, 5.495, 6.855, 6.197, 6.398, 7.468, 
                                 3.565, 3.891, 5.121, 3.319, 6.826, 5.235, 5.737, 5.703, 4.748, 
                                 5.693, 6.474, 5.836, 6.91, 5.616, 5.979, 5.604, 6.875, 6.48
                     ), Var2 = c(7.71, 7.85, 6.22, 6.93, 5.95, 5.98, 7.46, 1.26, 
                                 3.65, 3.42, 5.84, 3.31, 8.72, 7.88, 6.46, 8.05, 8.86, 5.62, 
                                 4.89, 6.42, 7.13, 5.63, 7.67, 2.84, 4.66, 4.57, 5.63, 6.62, 
                                 8.63, 8.64, 5.01, 3.43, 8.81, 5.72, 6.67, 5.12, 7.09, 6.05, 
                                 3.51, 7.46, 6.88, 5.64, 4.48, 5.68, 7.64, 4.56, 5.4, 7.27, 
                                 3.74, 7.67, 5.2, 7.83, 8.17, 7.09, 8.66, 9.11, 4.12, 2.87, 
                                 6.84, 6.36, 1.83, 8.71, 7.95, 6.59, 7.53, 6.92, 3.77, 6.72, 
                                 5.77, 4.83, 8.15, 5.81, 4.23, 4.3, 5.46, 8.92, 1.94, 5.48, 
                                 7.55), Var3 = c(1.51522335168878, 4.15325778828397, 2.94875838540978, 
                                                 1.00628430938346, 25.4230503312376, 8.18998374332489, 1.04538591988069, 
                                                 1.25351605643943, 1.03389499888613, 1.14765788536537, 1.26573001102583, 
                                                 1.07401182190831, 1.02601777187271, 1.03639332007889, 1.62605356699817, 
                                                 1.92725573397033, 1.01254164138481, 1.03505721838858, 3.46173219653658, 
                                                 1.08295832426121, 57.2882616377008, 1.20022298864129, NA, 
                                                 1.43549075453128, 1.01873682901296, 1.44946193787762, 1.64439543970553, 
                                                 1.00783008956213, 1.14205709505493, 1.08208397251952, 2.40225911107622, 
                                                 22.5235306849493, 1.36123323295883, 1.14848994633969, 1.27546825552435, 
                                                 1.15597071197187, 48.3011823156329, 1.24779693041552, 1, 
                                                 2.15232361681418, 1.10011380715122, 1.05904852323133, 1.67293114440204, 
                                                 1, 1.02209604887292, 1.26595913129412, 1.57959491321159, 
                                                 1.04583300104408, 1.00857974540892, 1.16022802219023, 206.447814325508, 
                                                 1.3232281172556, 1.01139457132996, 1.10081706683103, 3.18921374388388, 
                                                 1.0557568170143, 1.23896346376779, 1.03959784429336, 17.1956183236117, 
                                                 1.80633839574657, 10.3099601319805, 1.02590186237628, 1.02711959279389, 
                                                 3.88462180786233, 1.03514910690513, 6.23547964396164, 1.00861987775186, 
                                                 1.87180599797356, 1.19796183444303, 24.2411476428364, NA, 
                                                 1.02032998088937, 1.91697325378271, 5.22699733044137, 2.96243967880312, 
                                                 3.06551946990564, 1.07671406220387, 1.1343707501751, 1.01365610166913
                                 ), Var4 = c(5.02115486913067, 53.5285741103671, 39.4834327892571, 
                                             29.7359115979868, 47.9358701966989, 235.03977126673, 18.5573982408046, 
                                             66.6329529282582, 12.1943267185875, 35.520687621416, 7.748396902346, 
                                             14.0781314341043, 2.61247472515742, 16.4312138876475, 14.9790917560296, 
                                             4.67907440636335, 7.09540310138533, 102.616791283744, 88.2181889125004, 
                                             5.45216212311342, 34.0884625440838, 30.2003134971543, NA, 
                                             38.3702699384472, 8.57501351042922, 62.2004642089247, 76.6736686126914, 
                                             10.6413123736656, 7.5458791774842, 25.7491219067443, 164.757418389402, 
                                             55.2031078932382, 59.5510901036816, 43.3032934593257, 97.3114520688729, 
                                             18.165469164389, 320.319801025988, 13.0939299165512, 25.3489827724281, 
                                             77.8431685692976, 5.2221980923047, 4.11552340423602, 114.148376618668, 
                                             8.90737285506382, 16.7791925268633, 32.0409500313298, 4.91804723063735, 
                                             19.1290374537869, 5.54600968697425, 22.2985869624463, 154.740324753635, 
                                             12.8470204090039, 28.4518018574842, 34.8508421836621, 647.817331974169, 
                                             20.1107239887663, 115.849953826104, 8.01656186978807, 231.397986561214, 
                                             74.0235455862041, 652.332824392302, NA, NA, 4.41505603374484, 
                                             NA, 8.70787589323223, 11.2212181047515, 78.0819291629949, 
                                             6.75542213340634, 90.4249298288882, 69.6663541063077, 7.76768575885308, 
                                             36.5903131229487, 431.033230583165, 17.248411344137, NA, 
                                             27.1527603640721, 12.9134335737364, 14.6398591018054), Var5 = c(2.086, 
                                                                                                             5.23, 4.112, 2.896, 4.8, 5.36, 3.504, 4.398, 3.868, 4.356, 
                                                                                                             3.844, 2.862, 2.16, 3.862, 3.4, 1.56, 1.942, 5.954, 4.51, 
                                                                                                             1.89, 3.202, 3.83, 1.544, 3.68, 3.786, 5.52, 3.376, 3.058, 
                                                                                                             1.182, 3.758, 5.974, 4.14, 2.358, 5.226, 5.044, 4.178, 4.824, 
                                                                                                             3.776, 3.654, 3.72, 2.694, 3.542, 7.15, 2.99, 3.546, 4.582, 
                                                                                                             3.252, 3.396, 3.468, 2.954, 5.374, 3.732, 3.646, 5.1, 6.262, 
                                                                                                             2.566, 4.878, 5.414, 5.646, 5.224, 9.462, 0.618, 0.102, 1.76, 
                                                                                                             1.658, 2.804, 3.488, 5.7, 2.884, 5.012, 2.912, 3.788, 4.17, 
                                                                                                             7.862, 3.906, 1.836, 4.994, 3.882, 2.602), Var6 = c(43.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                 10.8, 7.5, 2.7, 21.5, 7.4, 27.4, 63.1, 1.5, 3.6, 1.1, 20, 
                                                                                                                                                                 1.4, 18.9, 27.7, 1.9, 0.8, 38.3, 32.4, 18.8, 3.2, 5.6, 1.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                 5, 42.2, 8.2, 14.5, 0.7, 1.6, 2.8, 41.4, 32, 5.6, 37.4, 42.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                 20.7, 39.9, 17.2, 21, 37.4, 0.6, 19, 26.6, 0.5, 1.1, 20.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                 18.1, 46.2, 17.1, 2.8, 26.9, 3.4, 22.7, 20.9, 52.6, 3.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                 47.3, 20.1, 56.3, 19.4, 56.6, 1.5, 27.1, 2.7, 7.8, 16.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                 1.4, 48.1, 1.3, 10.7, 22.2, 1.4, 28.2, 32.9, 22.7, 6.4, 24.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                 21, 3.9), Var7 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Var8 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Var9 = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, 0), Var10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Var11 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Var12 = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      15L, 18L, 21L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 43L, 46L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      48L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 62L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 76L, 80L, 81L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      88L, 89L, 90L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      113L, 114L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 123L, 124L, 127L, 130L, 135L, 136L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      138L, 139L, 141L, 143L, 146L, 150L, 153L, 156L, 160L, 162L, 163L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      164L, 167L, 170L, 171L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 179L, 181L, 182L, 184L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      185L), class = "data.frame")


model <- lm(formula = Dep_var ~ Var1 + Var2 + log(Var3) +
                 Var4 + Var5 + Var6 + Var7 + Var8 +
                 Var9 + Var10 + Var11 + Var12, 
                 data = df, 
                 na.action = na.exclude)


coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, method = "arellano", type = "HC3"))
```

Comment: The problem is nicely ameliorated by using the logit of the response instead of the response itself.  This indicates that logistic regression ought to work well, too.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your helpful comment, but could you elaborate a bit? Should I just take the logarithm of the dependent variable and then run what model?

Comment: Here are some things to do: `fit <- lm(log(Dep_Var/101) - log(1 - Dep_Var/101) ~ Var1 + Var2 + log(Var3) + Var4 + Var5 + Var6 + Var7 + Var8 + Var9 + Var10 + Var11 + Var12, 
          data = df, na.action = na.exclude);
df$Residual <- residuals(fit);
;
hist(df$Residual);

plot(fit)`

Comment: The logit transform I suggested above works well -- but, like the original model, it grossly overfits.  You have too few observations to fit a dozen parameters.  Repeated application of glmnet (50 times, with cross-validation) shows just six variables consistently look important, suggesting the model `log(Dep_Var/101) - log(1 - Dep_Var/101) ~ Var2 + log(Var3) + Var6 + Var8 + Var11 + Var12`.  That buys you a few more observations, too, because not as few now have a missing value.summary

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, tricky. Beta regression can be useful for something like this.  In beta regression, your outcome can be a fraction of stuff, so it lends itself naturally to these sorts of interval scales.  However, the outcome can never actually be 0 or 1 (or in your scale, 0 or 100) which poses a problem for your data.

One approach may be to simply compute `d$y - d$Dep_Var/100 - 0.001`, but that seems a bit hacky to me. It may be sufficient for what you want to do, but the best way would be to convince of a likelihood supported on [0,1].

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tired it out it worked. However the results are not very different from the OLS results. Maybe this will make it into the Appendix. Yes it's a statistical hellhole

Comment: just one additional question regarding the programming: How should the link argument be specified in this case? It's logit isn't it?

Comment: Logit is a fine link